# Self Prepuating Timer That Modifies GUI in Android

Tags: android, timer

I'm making an application and a certain part in my application I store a list of prices along with the time that the prices last for (they do not all last the same amount of time). So a price lasts a certain time then once that price's time is up it changes to another price (this part changes the UI or basically it updates a textview with the new price). So what I need is a timer that sets the timer again with the new time length and once it's done make the UI change. For instance say that each of the pairs represent the price amount and the time (in seconds): { {$2.53,1.4s}, {$4.57,4.45s}, {$1.23,3.6s}...}

So when the timer starts off the textview displays $2.53 and the timer lasts 1.4s and then it should grab the next price $4.57 and be set again but this time for 4.45s. This process continues on and on until the game is finished. I was thinking of using the CountDownTimer and resetting itself once the onFinish() method is called (I haven't verified if this idea works yet). Are there any other ideas?

Comment: Use simple Handler and its send[Empty]MessageDelayed() method

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a countdown timer and onFinish method you call back the function and it starts another timer:

```
private void startWheatPrices(long gameTime) 
{
    //other stuff executed
    StartWheatTimer(GameTimeDifference);//starts the timer for the first time
}
```

private void StartWheatTimer(long TimerAmount)
    {
        WheatTimer = new CountDownTimer(TimerAmount, 10) {

```
        public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) 
        {

        }

        public void onFinish() 
        {
            //other stuff executed
            WheatPricesTV.setText(Float.toString(PriceList.get(0).get(WheatPriceIndex).price));//price is changed 
            if(InGameplayMode)
                StartWheatTimer(convertToMilliseconds(PriceList.get(0).get(WheatPriceIndex).timeLength));//call back the function to start the timer again
        }
     }.start();
}
```